# Subversion with Eclipse for android

Tags: eclipse, svn

Okay I am starting to give up with this. I have been trying to setup sebversion in Eclipse for my android project. I have been following the following tutorial
http://blog.bauson.com/eclipse-subclipse-svn-hostgator-com.html

I got the following:

- Created a repository called myRep
- Created a project under with source files myRep/TestProject and attached it to trunk
- installed subclipse and got it to grab the repository

Now when, it says "Checkout as a project configured using the new project wizard", I get to choose the type of project. If I choose android application project then it creates a default android project and nothing is checked out. But when I choose General Project, it does grab the whole thing in the following structure
Repositony->TestProject->Trunk->All my android files and folders

However I want it to be android project so I can compile and run it. I did a lot of googling and I need your help pleeease!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I figured it out. Apperently, when you choose the repository you have to right click and click refresh and it will show you a list of Folders (stupid eclipse does not do it automatically). Then you choose your project and create it as a new project. Voilla, you get it compiling and running

Comment: It is good info that you found the solution. For the future: Subversion is independent of project type, SVN keeps all versions of the code. If you add to repository(commit) android project, you will have android project when you checkout it. Please take a look here: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/

Comment: Too add to the useful bits, Eclipse should auto-determine your project type from the [repo]/folder/.project file.